# Selecting the first child of an element that are not of the same parent

Tags: css, css-selectors

I might be wording this incorrectly so I apologize. Is there a way with CSS to target the first-child of an element but not the others when they are not grouped in the same parent? so for example:

```
    <div class="parent">
       <div class="littlekid">
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
       <div class="littlekid">
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
       <div class="littlekid">
    </div>
```

So say I would want the very first "littlekid" class in the very first "parent" to be red and all others to be blue. I have tried first-child, nth-of-type, nth-child, first-of-type and none seem to work. They all end up targeting all the "littlekid" classes. I can't add an extra class to the first "littlekid" to target it. Will this need to be done with javascript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that there are no other elements before the first `<div class="parent"></div>` within its parent you can use this:

```
div.parent > div.littlekid {
    color: blue;
}

div.parent:first-child > div.littlekid {
    color: red;
}
```

If there is more than one `<div class="littlekid">` within each parent you can also use this:

```
div.parent:first-child > div.littlekid:first-child {}
```